# Magento Sale Transaction Type

Tags: sales-order, transaction

I was wondering what is the best approach for implementing sale (auth with immediate capture from the gateway) transaction in Magento?

I would like to achieve the best possible compatibility with any potential workflows, 3rd -party observers and configurations.

Should i just call `parent::capture();` at the end of my authorize method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once again, in this great community, i am answering my own question.

After digging through the code, i found the cleanest approach (for run-time configurable transaction type) to be what PayPal actually uses: override `getConfigPaymentAction()` within your Model and insert a custom logic (based on your module configuration) that returns one of the following types:

`const ACTION_ORDER             = 'order';
const ACTION_AUTHORIZE         = 'authorize';
const ACTION_AUTHORIZE_CAPTURE = 'authorize_capture';`

In order to have both sale/capture, you'll need to modify your `capture()` method to check for previous Auth transactions.